# Meaning of "Never reach out your hand unless you're willing to extend an arm"

Tags: quotes

Please explain this quote to me:

> Never reach out your hand unless you're willing to extend an arm.
>
> http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/p/popepaulvi120370.html

How can one reach out for his hand? This part confuses me...

Comment: It means "Never ask unless you're willing to give".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Never reach out your hand unless you're willing to extend an arm](http://quotes.lifehack.org/quote/pope-paul-vi/never-reach-out-your-hand-unless-youre/) is a saying of Pope Paul VI which means **be prepared or willing to go all the way when offering help**.

In addition, [reach out your hand and touch somebody](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reach_Out_Your_Hand_%28And_Touch_Somebody%29) is a song by American country music artist Tammy Wynette released in April 1972. Another saying with the words reach out your hand is “dare to reach out your hand into the darkness, to pull another hand into the light." by African-American mayor Norman Blann Rice.

Answer (score 0):

It does not say "reach out *for* your hand" but "reach out your hand".

I understand it means something like:

"If you say A you should also say B"

i.e., be prepared that your first action might make it necessary to go for further actions.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the sentence.  The quote is

*Never reach out your hand unless you're willing to extend an arm.*

This does not mean that you reach out for your (own) hand.

It means that you reach out toward someone else who is in need, and offer them a (your) helping hand.  (*Reach out* has a sense meaning *extend/offer*)

The point of the phrase is to say that when you try and help someone (reach out your hand to offer support) you should be ready to offer as much more help ('your arm too') as may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Never reach out your hand unless you're willing to extend an arm.

In fact "reach out" and "extend" are used as synonyms here. A different verb is used simply for stylistic reasons - it avoids repetition.

**Paraphrase**

*Never extend your hand unless you are willing to extend your whole arm.*

**Meaning**

Don't offer to help someone if you are not prepared to follow through.